# Keep min value of two or more observations in R

Tags: r, subset, greatest-n-per-group, bigdata

So I have data on the long format about people taking general chemistry 1 in a university between 2005 and 2015.

The data look something like this

```
ID    Term    Grade  Repeated
260   2010     F          1
260   2011     F          1
260   2012     C          0
203   2011     B          0
204   2012     D          1
204   2013     B          1
```

As you can see some people took the class only once, and some repeated it once or twice. I am interested in keeping the grade of the first time they took the class.

Something is ID is repeated keepd the min(TERM) or something? I have like 250000 rows

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is sorted by `Term` then

```
df[!duplicated(df$ID),]
#   ID Term Grade Repeated
#1 260 2010     F        1
#4 203 2011     B        0
#5 204 2012     D        1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` package, you can do it as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Term == min(Term))

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: ID [3]

     ID  Term Grade Repeated
  <int> <int> <chr>    <int>
1   260  2010     F        1
2   203  2011     B        0
3   204  2012     D        1
```

Another option is to arrange by Term and take the first one as follows:

```
df %>% arrange(ID, Term) %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(1)
```

Giving the same output, but in a different order due to `arrange`:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: ID [3]

     ID  Term Grade Repeated
  <int> <int> <chr>    <int>
1   203  2011     B        0
2   204  2012     D        1
3   260  2010     F        1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unique` with `by` option after `order`ing by 'ID' and 'Term'

```
library(data.table)
unique(setorder(setDT(df1), ID, Term), by = "ID")
#    ID Term Grade Repeated
#1: 203 2011     B        0
#2: 204 2012     D        1
#3: 260 2010     F        1
```